# Nagios check_nt MEMUSAGE average

Tags: nagios, memory-usage

there is a method to check the memory (RAM) usage by the average in windows? (Like CPULOAD -l minutes)

Answer (score 0):

`check_nt` is deprecated. It exists only as a legacy plugin to monitor NSClient instances on Windows machines: these days, NSClient supports NRPE and as such you should use the "regular" `check_nrpe` plugin just as you would when checking a Linux machine running the nrpe daemon.

For information on how to check available memory via NSClient, please refer to the NSClient documentation: https://docs.nsclient.org/0.4.4/reference/windows/CheckSystem.html#CheckSystem.check_memory

Comment: I already use NRPE but don't know how to notificate if RAM as a critical after a hour for example. I don't want that nagios notificate me if RAM or CPU have a peak just 3 minutes.

Comment: Read up on the object configuration in nagios. How often checks run and when they notify is very much down to your configuration. For example the check interval, the retry interval, max attempts etc

Comment: I have found the "first_notification_delay" option now... After 3 bad days with escalations test that doesn't want to work

Comment: You don't want a notification delay, you want a combination of check interval, retry interval and max attempts that ensures the check consistently fails for an hour before reaching max attempts. Whether that's one check every minute 60 times or one every 10 minutes 6 times is irrelevant. Escalations is also something completely different. It's also very hard to help you since you provide no detail.